# Is peer to peer file transfer in android app possible?

Tags: android, p2p, file-transfer

I have searched a lot but not getting anything. I want to transfer over an internet connection in peer to peer communication. I do not want to upload file on the server and need to transfer directly to other user application in one to one connection. Is it feasible or not? I do not have much idea about how to follow Peer to peer communication architecture. Android providing p2p using wifi. (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) I want to do same using the internet.

Comment: What about WebRTC? It can send large chunks of data without the need for a server.

Comment: That's gonna be hard to achieve since you are on mobile device that will probably change it's ip address constantly (switching between different BTS, wifis etc)

Comment: you have to create a private network(more preferably VPN) for transfering data

Comment: @josemmo webRTC is a better option but I am not getting proper document how to implement it. It will be great if you can something that help me.